# I need to SAFELY use smileys - Need old version of MSN Toolbar - it's now Bing Toolbar

Tags: windows-xp, email, instant-messaging, emoticons, smiles

I had to reinstall the OS (Windows XP SP3), and now I can't find the old MSN Toolbar to download. It has been replaced with the Bing Toolbar.  The Bing toolbar doesn't have the options to use smileys (tools - icons - create -localize the icon on your PC).

I wan't to put smileys in my e-mails, etc.  How can I do this now???  Can I download an old version of the MSN Toolbar somewhere?

The only safe way I know of to safely use smileys was by following these instructions, using the old MSN Toolbar: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080518112819AAMXHfg  (Also, when you installed the MSN Toolbar, you did a custom installation and unchecked everything - so the toolbar didn't do anything else, and didn't slow broswing.)

Smileycentral.com, and all others I know of, are MALWARE - they slow browsing, track browsing, phone home, etc.  See for example: www(dot)pchell(dot)com/support/smileycentral.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Please do yourself and everyone you send emails to a favor and stop using smileys at all. Emoticons, as text, can be acceptable if used properly, but HTML email is a bad idea period, and that includes image smileys.

http://www.georgedillon.com/web/html_email_is_evil.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using emoticons from the unicode block instead.

These should be interpreted by anything that uses Unicode for its character base.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)